# OpenGL texturing Triangles

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a varray full of triangles that make a large square. I'm trying to texture this large square and all i'm getting (it seems) is a one pixel column that is then stretched across the primitive.

I'm texturing each right angled triangle with UV coords (0,1), (0,0), (1,0) and (0,1), (1,1), (1,0) depending on which way up the triangle is.

rendering code.

```
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture.id());

    //glEnableClientState(GL_INDEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    //glIndexPointer(GL_INT, 0, &m_indices[0]);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(VertexData), &m_vertexData[0].x);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, sizeof(VertexData), &m_vertexData[0].nx);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(UVData), &m_uvData[0].u);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, m_indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &m_indices[0]);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

texture is wrap mode is `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE`

[Screenshot](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2580523/coursework%202011-04-25%2020-11-08-27.png)

**EDIT**

outputting the first two triangles i get values ...

**Triangle 1:**

Indices(0,1,31)

Vertex0 (-15, 0, -15), Vertex1 (-15,0,-14), Vertex31 (-14, 0, -14)

UV (0,1), (0,0), (1,0)

**Triangle 2:**

Indices(0, 30, 31)

Vertex0(-15, 0, -15), Vertex30(-14, 0, -15) Vertex31 (-14, 0, -14)

UV (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0)

For posterity the full code is [here](http://pastie.org/1832861)

The two triangles make up a square with the diagonal cut from top left to bottom right.

Comment: You mean UV0, UV1, UV31, and UV0, UV30, and UV31, right?

Comment: @arasmussen, Your right about UV0, 1, 31, I was passing 0,1,2. I missunderstood the indices. I think I can only have 1 UV value per vertex.

Comment: Right. So really, you should pack it in with your VertexData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're associating the UV data with the indices, not with the vertices. UV data is part of the vertex data, so you should probably pack it in the VertexData object, rather than keeping it separate. You can keep it separate, but you need one per vertex, not one per index.

Comment: Thanks for your help, now I'm off to bed.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use the glIndexPointer, is not what you think it is, is used for color-index mode, to do indexed meshes just use glDrawElements.

Comment: lol Thanks, This is how we were show how to use it by my lecturer, and he is in desperate need to learn the topic again. It does not solve my problem tho :(

Comment: You should still not enable the client state for the index array.

Comment: @Jim Buck, I'm not anymore, I forgot to comment out the enable in the post above. With all the index array gone, I'm still left with a weird texture.

Comment: @arasmussen VertexData is a struct that holds the vertx data and normals, float x,y,z,nx,ny,nz It will draw the primitives correctly but not texture it right.

Comment: @PhilCK Try removing sizeof(UVData), and changing it to 0. Let me know what that does.

Comment: @PhilCK Is UVData a struct that holds the texcoords data (float u,v)?

Comment: @PhilCK Are you sure you've got the correct vertices/texcoords/indices? Could you please show us what the values are for your square? (should be 4 (x,y,z) coords, 4 (u,v) texcoords, and 6 indices depending on how you did it). Could just be that your texcoords are off.